# Cannot install psycopg2 with pip3 on M1 Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, psycopg2, apple-m1

I cannot install psycopg2 on my M1 Mac and I used pip3.

When I tried to install with **pip3** **install** **psycopg2** The output like that:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-install-9wiqe2nr/psycopg2_147a5ae8fd5a47079480274f4225edbf/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-install-9wiqe2nr/psycopg2_147a5ae8fd5a47079480274f4225edbf/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-06hnnl2t
         cwd: /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-install-9wiqe2nr/psycopg2_147a5ae8fd5a47079480274f4225edbf/
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-06hnnl2t/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-06hnnl2t/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-06hnnl2t/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-06hnnl2t/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-06hnnl2t/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    
    Error: pg_config executable not found.
    
    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:
    
        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
    
    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    
    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/ae/98cb7a0cbb1d748ee547b058b14604bd0e9bf285a8e0cc5d148f8a8a952e/psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz#sha256=fb23f6c71107c37fd667cb4ea363ddeb936b348bbd6449278eb92c189699f543 (from https://pypi.org/simple/psycopg2/) (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.5.tar.gz (380 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-install-9wiqe2nr/psycopg2_97efcf6747c249769acdc8430ba4238f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-install-9wiqe2nr/psycopg2_97efcf6747c249769acdc8430ba4238f/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ap2am61r
         cwd: /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-install-9wiqe2nr/psycopg2_97efcf6747c249769acdc8430ba4238f/
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ap2am61r/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ap2am61r/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ap2am61r/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ap2am61r/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/m5/vhnyyjg16gd352x6wdhpjysh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-ap2am61r/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    
    Error: pg_config executable not found.
    
    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:
    
        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
    
    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    
    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    ==============================================================================
    Its beginning of the error, After that its tried to install each previous version of Psycopg 
    ==============================================================================
```

Also, I tried to install with source code with :

git clone https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2.git
cd psycopg2
python3 setup.py build

Its return as error like that:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext

Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
```

Also 
python3 setup.py build
return the same error as `python3 setup.py build`

How can I install it?

Comment: Try `pip install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: It looks like you need pg_config installed

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Does `psycopg2-binary` [provide](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/#files) wheels for M1 architecture?

Comment: @phd not at all sure. Never tried it on M1 arch

Comment: I think its not available for M1 arch. Because I tried to all solving techniques but I get architecture error lastly.

Answer (score 98):

try this:

```
brew install libpq --build-from-source
brew install openssl

export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include"

pip3 install psycopg2
```

Comment: This worked perfectly fine for my M1. Thank you!

Comment: I can't believe it, 
it worked for me I tried so many times and ways from many resources specifically GitHub `psycopg2` GitHub page but after deleting the pyenv python version and install it again it worked, thank you

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what the issue was and how this fixes it?

Comment: to work on m1 mac run `arch -arm64 brew install libpq --build-from-source`

Comment: For M2, switch `openssl@1.1` to `openssl@3.1`.

Answer (score 35):

Before reverting to any of the older answers, I would recommend trying the following:

Install Postgres using `brew install postgres`, then `pip3 install psycopg2`.

Worked on Mac M1, Monterey, Python 3.9.

Thanks to [Kori Vernon](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1200#issuecomment-985748635).

Comment: i did the same, and problem solved.

Comment: but i have a question, if how do i put `brew install postgres` in requirements.txt?

Comment: @yts61 You can't. If you need `requirements.txt` for some kind of automated deployment, you can create small shell script, that first installs OS dependencies like postgresql with `brew` on the first line and then runs something like `pip install -r requirements.txt` (or pip3 instead of pip) on the second line.

Comment: `brew install postgresql@14`

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to active development, now there is a new release of psycopg2 as well as psycopg2-binary which is compatible with M1 devices.
Ver. 2.9.1 works smooth. Tried and tested
Reference - https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1200

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is install the binary:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Everything has been running fine since. I referenced [this link](https://rogulski.it/blog/install-psycopg2-on-apple-m1/) and just skipped straight to the last step. If installing the binary doesn't work on the first try, I would take a look at the other steps in this article.

Comment: I am using a Mac m1 air and this worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

Following this steps solved my problem:

```
❯ brew install postgresql@14
# If you open a new terminal tab you will see that pg_config is available
❯ export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
❯ export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L${HOME}/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib" # use your current python version
❯ python -V
Python 3.10.7 # make sure it matches the same above configuration
❯ pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install openssl
```

Check out which version of openssl is installed!

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@**{YOUR_OPENSSL_VERSION}**/include"

python -V

export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@**{YOUR_OPENSSL_VERSION}**/lib -L${HOME}/.pyenv/versions/**{YOUR_PYTHON_VERSION}**/lib"

pip install psycopg2-binary
```

works on mac m1

Answer (score 0):

Install the PostgreSQL and OpenSSL system libraries:

```bash
brew install libpq --build-from-source
brew install openssl
```

Configure the linker and header search paths by setting the `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` environment variables. Instead of hard-coding the OpenSSL version, we determine the version path using `brew --prefix`:

```bash
export LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include"
```

Now you should be able to install the `psycopg2` dependency by running `pip`:

```bash
pip install psycopg2
```

These instructions are compatible with Apple Silicon.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble today installing psycopg2 on my new Macbook Pro with an M3 chip. To fix this, I installed postgres from the command line using brew, then ran the recommended commands to add postgres to my PATH, closed my terminal window where I was attempting to install psycopg2, then opened a new terminal window and installed psycopg2:

`$ brew install postgresql@15`

`$ echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

`$ export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/lib"`

`$ export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/include"`

Open a NEW terminal window to install psycopg2:

`$ pip install psycopg2`